# What .NET class should I use to represent a subnet and its mask?

Tags: c#, .net, subnet

I can use `System.Net.IPAddress` to represent a single IP Address, but what can I use to represent an entire subnet, including the network address and the subnet mask?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use the System.Net.IPAddress to also represent a subnet mask.  It's of the same form, and the only real operation you need to do w/ it is a bitmask based on the bytes of the subnet address.

```
System.Net.IPAddress i = System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse("10.10.1.1");
Byte[] b = i.GetAddressBytes();
```

Comment: apologies - my question didn't match the title.  I've fixed the title.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct NetworkIPAddress
{
  public IPAddress IP;
  public uint Mask;
}
```